# Load images one by one after each sucessfull drop for dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

want to load images one by one after each successful drop for dragging

another image should load in place of the same place where first image is dragged from for a second drag.

how to implement it.i have achieved drag and drop of first image , what is the change and how is it possible

i have tried many many ways im a newbie in js is it possible in js

```js
function drop006(event) {
var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice001");
event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
score001.innerHTML = b++;
place001.innerHTML = " <'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random' alt = 'infinix' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>";

}    

function dragStart001(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("choice001", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop001(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}


function drop001(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}


var imgArray = new Array();
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random';
imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random';
imgArray[5] = new Image();
imgArray[5].src = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random';


function pushArray(element) {
  var img = document.getElementById(imgArray);
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
 if (imgArray[i].src == img.src) {
   if (i === imgArray.length) {
  document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
  break;
   }

   document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i + 1].src;
   break;
 }
  }
}
```

```css
.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: :url(clock.jpg);
  margin: -50px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop006(event)" ondragover="allowDrop001(event)" id="place001" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/100/100/)">
</div>


<div class="box002" ondrop="drop001(event)" id="plac002" ondrop="pushArray()">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/?random" ondragstart="dragStart001(event)" draggable="true" id="target001" style="width:200px; height:200px;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use Dropzone Js  Plugin for this.https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: is there a pure javascript function if method for achieving this

Comment: where is located the declaration of drop006() ?

Comment: i have included the drop006()..please check